# In SQLPLUS, can't name the view column as number

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I tried to create a view using

```
 VIEW PERSONNEL30 (NAME, NUMBER, JOB, HIREDATE) 
AS (SELECT SNAME, STAFFID, JOB, STARTDATE FROM STAFF WHERE BRANCHID = 30);
```

But I got an error message that says "invalid identifier" and * below NUMBER. When I change it to NUM it works. Why can't I use NUMBER? I thought it could be a reserved word but it isn't. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`NUMBER` is an [Oracle reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).  It is a data type, akin to `NUMERIC`.

In order to use it as an identifier, you would have to enclose it in double quotes `"NUMBER"`.  However, I strongly encourage you to find another name that does not need to be quoted, such as `staff_number` or whatever.